# Why is there no "reduced ads" privilege at 200 reputation on this site?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, reputation

By accident I found out that on this site the privilge **reduced ads** at 200 reputation does not exist according to [the help page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Is there a reason for this?

Comment: [Because it doesn't exist yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329812/332043).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246563/295232) seems to suggest there are no ads on Chemistry (except for the sidebar) and the privilege is therefore hidden:

> The privilege *exists* everywhere. But on most sites, it's hidden and notifications for earning it are suppressed. Doesn't make much sense to tell folks about a privilege that doesn't actually *do* anything.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308416/295232) is another answer which more or less claims the configuration is up-to-date.